# convert .txt file into a list of integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, I have a file which has the following content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I want create it into a list of integers in Python3, i.e [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

```
f = open("stan.txt","r")

myList = []

for line in f:
   myList.append(line)

print(myList)

lst = []
for i in myList:
    i = i[:-1]
    lst.append(int(i))
print(lst)
```

It is my verbose code. Is there an elegant and concise way to do it?

Comment: The numbers in txt file should be written not in one line but in subsequent files. I wrote it this way but it changed

Comment: Edit your question then.

Comment: Could you please tell how to do it?

Comment: `for line in f: myList.append(int(line))`

Comment: This question is such a duplicate, its duplicates have duplicates.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not very large, read it as a string, split the string into numbers, and apply `int()` to each of them using list comprehension:

```
with open("stan.txt") as f:
    lst = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wish I could upvote it.

Comment: The only downside here is that you're reading all of the file into memory before processing it rather than iterating over it line by line.

Comment: @rumdrums As I said, it works when the file is not large.

Answer (score -1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
with open('stan.txt') as f:
  my_list = [ int(i) for i in f ]
```

Comment: `int()` removes spaces, no need to `.rstrip()`.